# Include figure from pdf file to a document class of two side article

Tags: graphics, floats, multicol

I want to include a figure from Pdf file to a LaTeX document, which I have done before by using

```
 \includegraphics{42.pdf}
```

But today I want to write a paper using latex so I change my document class to

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
```

then I try to add Pdf figure, then the problem stat, when I try compiling this the document compiles and there is no error in the code, but no figure shows up in Pdf

here is my code

```
   \documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{abstract}
    \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{\vspace{-15mm}
\fontsize{24pt}{8pt}\selectfont
\textbf{Test latex file}}   
\author[1,*]{Andreas}
\author[2,**]{Lulu}

\affil[1]{\normalsize Department of Physics and Astronomy, College of Science}
\affil[2]{\normalsize Department of Physics, College of Science}
\affil[*,**]{a@gmail.com ,s@gmail.com}
\vspace{-5mm}
\date{May 2015}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\noindent In quantum optics
\end{abstract}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Introduction} 
test test test 
test test test 
test test test 
test test test 
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{42.pdf}
\caption{{\protect\footnotesize Test.}}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
test test test 
test test test 
test test test 
test test test 

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you haven't really given any information that would allow anyone to help you. make a small,  complete, example without all those unrelated packages that shows the problem and post the complete file and the log that you get. Unrelated but you never want to load `epsfig` unless you need to emulate documents from 1985.

Comment: Please read the manual to the multicol package, it does not support floats, so no figure. This has nothing to do with twoside.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry I always put all the packages that maybe I will need them, anyway I try to shortcut the code

Comment: @daleif oh, Is there anther way to replace multicol package
without changing the page design ?

Comment: Not really. Just take a look at the documentation for information about handling floats. But the reason they are incompatible is because the package is trying to solve quite a difficult problem. It isn't an arbitrary whim on the part of the package's creator. So the problem is that any similar package would encounter similar difficulties.